# Making JavaScript Custom ScrollBar

Tags: javascript

I said **“JavaScript”**. I'm trying to make my own JavaScript custom scrollbar. It's almost successful. The problem is that I can't get an accurate multiplier for the scrolling speed. This is my code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('scroll-area'),
    track = elem.children[1],
    thumb = track.children[0],
    height = parseInt(elem.offsetHeight, 10),
    cntHeight = parseInt(elem.children[0].offsetHeight, 10),
    trcHeight = parseInt(track.offsetHeight, 10),
    distance = cntHeight - height,
    mean = 50, // For multiplier (go faster or slower)
    current = 0;

elem.children[0].style.top = current + "px"; // Set default `top` value as `0` for initiation
thumb.style.height = Math.round(trcHeight * height / cntHeight) + 'px'; // Set the scrollbar thumb hight

var doScroll = function (e) {

    // cross-browser wheel delta
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

    // (1 = scroll-up, -1 = scroll-down)
    // Always check the scroll distance, make sure that the scroll distance value will not
    // increased more than the content height and/or less than zero
    if ((delta == -1 && current * mean >= -distance) || (delta == 1 && current * mean < 0)) {
        current = current + delta;
    }

    // Move element up or down by updating the `top` value
    elem.children[0].style.top = (current * mean) + 'px';
    thumb.style.top = 0 - Math.round(trcHeight * (current * mean) / cntHeight) + 'px';

    e.preventDefault();

};

if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", doScroll, false);
    elem.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", doScroll, false);
} else {
    elem.attachEvent("onmousewheel", doScroll);
}
```

And the markup:

```
<div id="scroll-area">
    <div><!-- CONTENT --></div>
    <span class="scrollbar-track"><span class="scrollbar-thumb"></span></span>
</div>
```

My problem is on `mean = 50`. When you scroll the container until the bottom of content, the red line that I made in the demo page should stop right at the bottom of the container, not higher than  that.

Anyone have an idea for the accurate result?

**PS:** I also want to add a function that will enable user to scroll the content by dragging the scrollbar thumb. But I think I want to focus on this issue first. Thanks for your help.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2B8Ye/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have done this much much easier.
Instead of calculating the `top` property for the container you can set its `scrollTop` property, and you guess what - you don't have to check if the content moves upper than 0 or lower than height because `scrollTop` property **can not be set to a value smaller than 0 or greater than container's height**!

[Here's your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVsVq/13/)

Notice that I had to wrap everything with additional `<div id="everything">...</div>` so the scrollbar won't be scrolled together with the `#scroll-area` div.

Also I assume using `clientHeight` instead of `offsetHeight` for `.scroll-content` div to include padding in the `cntHeight` variable.

More info on the `scrollTop` property you can find in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop) article.

Comment: I'v already tried to use the `scrollTop` before, but it didn't work for hidden overflow. Not sure how you can do this with hidden overflow. But now you've solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think the easiest way to understand this is to prepare a box with `overflow:scroll` and examine its behaviour. When you do so, you'll notice that you get the native scrollbar. When you scroll the content, its `scrollTop` property changes. My jsfiddle solution is exactly opposite - we modify `scrollTop` property to scroll the content. What `overflow:hidden` does, is only hiding native scrollbar.